# MINVERSE only returns a single number

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2011

For the life of me, I can not get the `MINVERSE` function on Excel 2011 on my Apple Macbook to work.

I entered the function into a matrix.

I type `=MINVERSE(A1:C3)`, the location of my matrix to be inverted in A1:C3

I've tried many times pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to get a full matrix, but I only get 1 number in 1 cell all the time.

I did press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> together.

Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I figured out the answer, and I'd like to keep this here for the record for anyone else who may have forgotten this step.

Before you enter the function, it's important to select all the cells you will need in the inverse! For example, if you are trying to invert a 3x3 matrix, you must first select a 3x3 output range before entering the `MINVERSE` formula.

After you select the cells to represent the entries in the inverse matrix, then you enter the formula into one of them and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> simultaneously.

This should work.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 1):

Only thing that worked for me:

1. Select the target cell
2. Type the formula in the input line
3. Open the Function Wizard dialog **before** clicking the `Enter` key
4. *Tick the "Array" checkbox*
5. Click the "OK" button

Comment: That *can't* be the *only* thing that works for you. You can always select the full output range first, before typing the formula and `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`ing it. In fact you can also enter the formula in a single cell first, select the full output range (with the formula cell the active cell), press `F2` and *then* CSE. This method is just another (useful) way to do it.